# Input() failing to assign a value to a name

Tags: python, input, nameerror

I am building a fairly large function that requires user input at the start using `pick` and `input`. I am working in python 3.8 in the python terminal.

I am using `last_6 = input("What is your average milage for the last 6 weeks?)` to assign a user input value to the name `last_6`. When I call the function, I am asked for the input value, but then the function fails to move to the next step.

Calling the name that should now return input value `last_6`, results in the error message

```
NameError: name 'last_6' not is not defined .
```

The first section of the function, up until when the error occurs can be seen here:

```
def milage_calc():
    title = 'What event are you training for?'
    options = [ '800', '1500/mile','3k/2mile', '5k', '10k', 'Half Marathon', 'Marathon' ]
    event = pick(options, title, multiselect= False)

    event_dict = {'800': 0.7, '1500/mile': 0.75,'3k/2mile': 0.8, '5k': 0.9, '10k': 1 , 'Half Marathon': 1.1, 'Marathon': 1.2, }
    event_modifier = event_dict[event[0]]

    weeks = list(range(1,20,1))
    _20_weeks_milage = {}


    last_6 = input("what is your average weekly milage over the last 6 weeks? Please give your answer as a whole number:")
```

The terminal displays `what is your average weekly milage over the last 6 weeks? Please give your answer as a whole number:`.

I then input the answer, and hit enter. But the rest of the function doesnt run. When I call the name associated with the input value `last_6`, I just get `NameError: name 'last_6' is not defined`.

The full function can be seen here:

```
def milage_calc() :
    title = 'What event are you training for?'
    options = [ '800', '1500/mile','3k/2mile', '5k', '10k', 'Half Marathon', 'Marathon' ]
    event = pick(options, title, multiselect= False)

    event_dict = {'800': 0.7, '1500/mile': 0.75,'3k/2mile': 0.8, '5k': 0.9, '10k': 1 , 'Half Marathon': 1.1, 'Marathon': 1.2, }
    event_modifier = event_dict[event[0]]

    weeks = list(range(1,20,1))
    _20_weeks_milage = {}


    last_6 = input("what is your average weekly milage over the last 6 weeks? Please give your answer as a whole number:")

    # check that milage input is in the right format
    while type(last_6) != int:
        print("You didn't input your milage as a whole number, please try again.")
        last_6 = int(input("what is your average weekly milage over the last 6 weeks? Please give your answer as a whole number:" ))

    if 0 > last_6 or 100 < last_6:
        print("Please re-enter your milage to confirm that it is correct")
        last_6_2 = input("what is your average weekly milage over the last 6 weeks? Please give your answer as a whole number:")

    if last_6_2 == last_6:
        None
    else:
        print("Your entries did not match. Please re-enter your milage to confirm that it is correct. Becareful because your training plan will \n be created using the milage you enter this time")
        last_6 = input("what is your average weekly milage over the last 6 weeks? Please give your answer as a whole number:")
        # User inputs the ave. milage per week for their biggest 6 weeks of the last year

    best_6 = input("In the last year, what is your highest 6 week average milage? Please give your answer as a whole number:")

    # check that milage input is in the right format
    while type(best_6) != int:
        print("You didn't input your milage as a whole number, please try again.")
        best_6 = input("In the last year, what is your highest 6 week average milage? Please give your answer as a whole number:")

    if 0 > best_6 or 100 < best_6:
        print("Please re-enter your milage to confirm that it is correct")
        best_6_2 = input("In the last year, what is your highest 6 week average milage? Please give your answer as a whole number:")
    if best_6_2 == best_6:
        None
    else:
        print("Your entries did not match. Please re-enter your milage to confirm that it is correct. Becareful because your training plan will \n be created using the milage you enter this time")
        best_6 = input("what is your average weekly milage over the last 6 weeks? Please give your answer as a whole number:")

    # Calculating the milage for each week of the 20 weeks of the training plan.
    for x in weeks:
        if x in [1,2,3]:
            _20_weeks_milage[x] = 10 + 0.9*((last_6)+x*0.2*(best_6 - last_6))

        elif x in [4,8,12,16]:
            _20_weeks_milage[x]= 0.75*_20_weeks_milage[(x-1)]
        elif x in [5,6,7,9,10,11,13]:
            _20_weeks_milage[x]= best_6 + 3*(x-5)
        elif x in [14,15,17,18]:
            _20_weeks_milage[x]= (_20_weeks_milage[13]-((1.5*x)-13))*event_modifier
        else :
            _20_weeks_milage[x]= (_20_weeks_milage[16]*(0.50+((20-x)*0.125)))*event_modifier

    return print(_20_weeks_milage)
```

Comment: Please be mindful to format your code properly! It is very difficult to debug code if we must tell actual from formatting errors. You can [edit] your question to fix the formatting. Please also take a look at the [mcve] help page.

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but your first `last_6 = input(...)` needs to be `last_6 = int(input(...))`.  Otherwise, the result is a string, and your `type(last_6) != int` is always true.

Comment: you need to define last_6 before the function @Yellin is saying correct

Comment: Did you try to access `last_6` from the python terminal?

Answer (score 0):

As Frank has commented, `input()` always returns a string, this makes your loops fail. To check if your input can be safely converted to an integer, you can use the `.isdigit()` method. This will however only work for integers. Here's the first loop of your code rewritten with this in mind:

```
last_6 = input("what is your average weekly milage over the last 6 weeks? " 
"Please give your answer as a whole number:")

# check that milage input is in the right format
while not last_6.isdigit():
    print("You didn't input your milage as a whole number, please try again.")
    last_6 = input("what is your average weekly milage over the last 6 weeks? "
    "Please give your answer as a whole number:")
last_6 = int(last_6)
```

Also, the code you posted is not formatted correctly, I had to guess at some indentations...

Comment: How is that related to the alleged ``NameError: name 'last_6' not is not defined`` that question actually asks about?

Comment: I have no idea how where that error came from, actually - look at the code, the function just gets stuck at the input of `last_6_2` or `best_6`. Maybe they tried to access `last_6` from outside the function?

Comment: I also don't know where the error possibly comes from, but it is what the question asks about.